# Posting data to JSON - Angular .post

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I am working on an application and am having an issue posting to a `.JSON` file in my assets.  I am working with an `Angular` based application.  The error code I get is `404` with a response of: `Cannot POST /assets/data/card-stack.json`.  Now the problem is, when I work with my `get` to retreive the `JSON` data it works perfect.  It is only when I am using `.post`.  Here is what I am doing:

```
$http.get('./../../assets/data/card-stack.json').success(function(data) {
                $scope.cards = data;
                // Set the showdown images from the card data grabbed from the card-stack.json file
                $scope.showdowns = [
                    $scope.cards[0].url,
                    $scope.cards[1].url,
                    $scope.cards[2].url,
                    $scope.cards[3].url
                ];
        });
        // Simple POST request example (passing data) :
        $http.post('./../../assets/data/card-stack.json', {url : './../images/banana.jpg'}).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // this callback will be called asynchronously
            // when the response is available
          }).
          error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              console.log(data);

            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
         });
```

Suggestions?

Comment: The first parameter of post is url and second one is data to be posted.

Comment: yes?  url :.. is simply data to be applied to url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .json file is a static file that just contains json data so you won't be able to post to it. Instead you would need to use a server side page or service such as php to process the posted data.

Comment: So Angular and whatnot does not handle that process for you?  Instead i should use a .php file to write to the .json file than?

Comment: Yes, normally you would use some backend data storage such as a database to store the data instead of a .json file. .json files are ok for testing get actions

Comment: this is a locally running application using mongod.

Comment: Since you are using Mongo db you could use NodeJs. Take a look at http://mean.io/

Comment: I am utilizing nodejs

Comment: Yeah so instead you would post to your server to update your db and the get would fetch from the db

Comment: So there is no way to do it simply through nodejs to upload data into the json file or is it better to just create a php file to write the data there?

Comment: What is the .json file used for? Why are you using mongo db instead? If you wanted to you could update the json file from nodejs

Comment: I am using the json file to store my data.  I have JSON objects that are read and populate data to my local webpage I am simply trying to write to the JSON objects and update some data inside that same file for those values.  I am trying to figure out how to write that in.

Comment: My confusion was, I thought the $http.post above was what would write directly to the JSON file.

Comment: yeah, the server will need to do it. You could use nodejs writeFile to do it: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback

Comment: I am als using gruntjs if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the $http header:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
```

Try it.